# Git : Given MR id , how to find corresponding target branch?

Tags: git, gitpython

I was going through git commands and I was not able to find a command that takes in MR id and gives somthing like merge request object from where I can get target branch. Is there any such git command ?

Also I am using GitPython so if there is any API in the package, that would also work.

Comment: merge requets / pull requets are not a _git_ concept so do not expect to get support for that from plain git.

Comment: Adding to eftshift0 's comment: so you will have to turn to the api of your git service (gitlab, github, devops ...)